# getting googleapp into work and errors

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to get into work a code with googleapp engine, but always face with following errors:

> ERROR    2011-04-27 16:30:44,538
>   appcfg.py:254] Could not find version
>   file at
>   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/google/../VERSION
>   ERROR    2011-04-27 16:30:44,539
>   appcfg.py:254] Could not find version
>   file at
>   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/google/../VERSION
>   INFO     2011-04-27 16:30:44,540
>   appengine_rpc.py:158] Server:
>   appengine.google.com ERROR
>   2011-04-27 16:30:44,540 appcfg.py:254]
>   Could not find version file at
>   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/google/../VERSION
>   ERROR    2011-04-27 16:30:44,540
>   appcfg.py:407] Could not determine if
>   the SDK supports the api_version
>   requested in app.yaml. ERROR
>   2011-04-27 16:30:44,543 appcfg.py:254]
>   Could not find version file at
>   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/google/../VERSION
>   INFO     2011-04-27 16:30:44,543
>   appcfg.py:435] Skipping update check
>   WARNING  2011-04-27 16:30:44,543
>   datastore_file_stub.py:655] Could not
>   read datastore data from
>   /tmp/dev_appserver.datastore

I re-installed googleapp-engine again, but nothing happen ...

Comment: Can you post your app.yaml?  It looks like you may be missing the `version` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion of the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3050). As a quick fix, you can try this:

`sudo ls -s ~/google_appengine/VERSION /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/VERSION`

Comment: It works, I only replaced your "ls" with "cp" sudo cp -s ~/google_appengine/VERSION /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/VERSION